# textarea generated by pug has cursor starting in the middle

Tags: forms, sass, textarea, pug

I'm creating a form with Pug and in the resulting textarea the cursor starts in the middle instead of the top left. I've seen similar questions where the issue was whitespace between the opening and closing input tags but this can't be the case for me since I'm not writing HTML directly.

admin.pug:

```
form.basic#alertEditor(name="alertEditor" v-on:submit.prevent="createAlert" autocomplete="off")
    label(for="title") Title
    input(type="text", name="title", v-model="title", required)
    label(for="startDate") Start Date
    input(type="date", name="startDate", v-model="startDate", required)
    label(for="endDate") End Date
    input(type="date", name="endDate", v-model="endDate", required)
    label(for="desc") Description
    input(type="textarea", name="desc", v-model="desc" required)
```

style.sass

```
form.basic
  display: block
  input:not([type="radio"]), label:not([for="alert"]):not([for="detour"]), select
    display: block
  input, select
    margin-bottom: 1em
    font-family: "museo-sans", sans serif
    border-radius: 4px
  select
    padding: 0.5em 1em
    font-size: 1.05em
  input
    padding: 1em
  input[type="text"],input[type="date"],input[type="password"],input[type="email"]
    border: 2px solid $tertiary
    width: 100%
  input[type="textarea"]
    border: 2px solid $tertiary
    width: 50%
    height: 150px
```

I've tried setting the rows and cols attributes as well as width and height but the issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`textarea` is not a [valid `<input>` type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input). You should use the [`<textarea>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea) instead.

```
label(for='desc') Description
textarea#desc(name='desc', v-model='desc', required)
```

Also, note that the `for` attribute on [`<label>` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) should match the `id` (not `name`) of the form element it labels.

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe it was something so simple. I should have known that

Comment: @PaulMcDowell I've made that mistake before too